# Thunderbird Supernova Quick Filter motion/animation in Vertical Layout

Tags: macos, thunderbird

Whenever I press a button on a Quick Filter Toolbar (QF), the entire QF toolbar shifts to the left to provide some space for the text showing the number of selected messages.

[image: Quick Filter Toolbar shifting position when clicked]

I find this motion/animation highly distracting. Is there any way to prevent Quick Filter Toolbar from moving when a button is pressed?  I also don't need to see the number of selected messages.

(Thunderbird 115.2.0 on Mac OS, Thunderbird in Vertical Layout)